# Stack up on each other or stack on one another

Tags: word-usage

My girlfriend and I saw a meme on Instagram of a house surrounded by treadmills titled **"How to survive the Zombie apocalypse"**. After seeing it, my girlfriend said **"I don't think this would work; they would all stack on one another",** and then she asked me whether "**they would stack on one another**" is correct, and I couldn't answer her question because I got confused myself, being a non-native speaker. I would've said "**they would all stack up on top of each other"** but I'm not sure....

Answer (score 1):

> They would all stack on top of one another

Nothing you or your girlfriend said is necessarily wrong, but the most idiomatic way to say it would be the above.